# mysqli_query() and mysqli_fetch_array() expects at least 2 parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

In this code previously worked well in PHP5.X version now i have to convert this code in PHP7. But not working properly.
I need to get data from database and show that data in site.

I am running Xammp v7.3.3 in windows server 2012. PHP7 and MySQL.

```
    <?php
     /* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
     server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
     define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
     define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
     define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
     define('DB_NAME', 'reqplan');

    /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

     // Check connection
     if($link === false){
     die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
         }
     ?>

    <?php
        include "connect.php";
        $i = "select * from reqplan";
        $h = mysqli_query($i);
        while($tr=mysqli_fetch_array($h))
        {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $tr[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tr[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tr[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tr[3]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tr[4]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tr[5]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tr[6]; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $tr[7];?></td>
        <td><? echo $tr[8];?></td>
        <td><? echo $tr[9];?></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="Delete_Form.php?txtid=<?php echo $tr[0];?>">Delete</a> / <a href="Edit_Form.php?txtid=<?php echo $tr[0];?>&date1=<?php echo $tr[1]; ?>&team1=<? echo $tr[2];?>&recname1=<? echo $tr[3];?>&client=<? echo $tr[4];?>&location=<? echo $tr[5];?>&mode=<? echo $tr[6];?>&jobcode=<? echo $tr[7];?>&reqdetails=<? echo $tr[8];?>&psch=<? echo $tr[9];?>">Edit</a> </td>    
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Database select was not working properly.
Shows error

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in E:\xampp7\htdocs\reqplan\login\index.php on line 50
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in E:\xampp7\htdocs\reqplan\login\index.php on line 51

Comment: That is correct... make it so!

Comment: The error message says it all, `$h = mysqli_query($i);` should be `$h = mysqli_query($link, $i);`

Comment: Thanks @Nick Its worked but Still
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in E:\xampp7\htdocs\reqplan\login\index.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this
You have to pass db connect value also

```
 while(mysqli_fetch_array($h,$link))
```

Comment: Thanks @Future Coder but error same.
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in E:\xampp7\htdocs\reqplan\login\index.php

Comment: Mysqli_fetch_array does not require the connection object. Read the documentation before posting!